# Simple scroll view constraints change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I created a scroll view in Xcode that works awesome because of this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PIm8-lKAYw

When I was messing around after I made it I found out that if I clicked on the scroll view and went to Show the Size Inspector or the fifth button on the right hand side of the screen I had the option to make a constraint called Top Space change in value that caused the scroll view to become bigger and smaller. I decided to see if I could find a way to change the constraint programmatically by simply using dot notation and the equaling it to an int value that I wanted.

So what I'm trying to figure out is there a simple way to change these constraints values programmatically that change the scroll view constraints values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Without actually following that tutorial (and there being no code in your question) I'm going to make a few assumptions.*

Yes, it is possible to change the scroll view's content size by manipulating constraints in your code. If you are creating the constraints in a xib or storyboard, you will need to make sure they are hooked up to `IBOutlet`s so that you can access them in your code.

If you have 2 views arranged vertically that affect the vertical content size of your scroll view, increasing the space between these views would also increase the vertical size of your scrollview's content size. The following would increase the space between 2 views by 20 (assuming a multiplier of 1) and subsequently increase the scrollview's vertical space by the same amount.

```
// This is a vertical space constraint created in your xib or storyboard between 2 views that drive the content size of your scrollview
someVerticalSpaceConstraint.constant += 20;
```

Comment: Dude thank you so much this is exactly what I needed! I'm sorry you had to answer such a simple question. Still new to all this...But you made my day with this man! Thanks again

Comment: Oh sorry I will now then.